# Creating a table from query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server

Here is my 2 sql query on the first query i want to use it as a table and on the 2nd query i want to join the 1st query which i assume a table

e.g.

First query:

```
SELECT sale.salesManID, sale.companyName, sale.sellingPrice 
from sale Inner Join carModel 
On (sale.companyName = carModel.companyName) AND (carModel.size>10) ;
```

Second Query:

```
SELECT salesMan.salesmanID, salesMan.name, SUM(firstQuery.sellingPrice)
FROM salesMan 
INNER JOIN firstQuery 
ON salesMan.salesmanID = firstQuery.salesManID
GROUP BY salesmanID, name;
```

How can i do it ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you want to do ? `sql join query results` Who do you ask this question first ? `google`. You will find at least 5 questions on this.

Comment: What do you mean by "use query as a table"? Table is for storing data, query is for getting data...

Comment: No Sir suppose i run the first query a table will be created 
then by using that table i want to inner join it with the 2nd query

Comment: @user3148422 - Why do you want to do it that way ? Again `google` is your friend - sql server temporary table, insert query results into table, sql join query results. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly (although I'm not sure why you'd want to do it this way...):

> IF object_id('tempdb..#firstQuery) IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #firstQuery;
>
> SELECT sale.salesManID, sale.companyName, sale.sellingPrice
>   INTO #firstQuery
>   FROM sale Inner Join carModel  On (sale.companyName =
>   carModel.companyName) AND (carModel.size>10) ;
>
> SELECT salesMan.salesmanID, salesMan.name,
>   SUM(firstQuery.sellingPrice) FROM salesMan  INNER JOIN #firstQuery  ON
>   salesMan.salesmanID = firstQuery.salesManID GROUP BY salesmanID,
>   name;

Answer (score 0):

it's not a clear question. do you mean using subquery on join???

maybe you can take a look to this threads:

[mysql subquery inside a LEFT JOIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12309892/mysql-subquery-inside-a-left-join)

[MySQL correlated subquery in JOIN syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/530381/mysql-correlated-subquery-in-join-syntax)

or just google [mysql join subquery](https://encrypted.google.com/search?aq=f&oq=mysql%20join%20subquery&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=mysql%20join%20subquery)

also you can take a look this post: [How can my application benefit from temporary tables?e](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116423/how-can-my-application-benefit-from-temporary-tables)