# mysql search in multiple joined tables (7 tables with 6 joins)

Tags: mysql, sql, database, performance, join

I'm trying to search in multiple tables. I followed normalization rules in designing my database. I have 7 tables explained in this [schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NtKGy.png).

I built a view to get the interesting columns out of these tables.

```
ALTER ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED DEFINER = `root`@`localhost` SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `port_data_view` AS

SELECT `s`.`tel_subscriber_number` AS `phone`
    ,`s`.`tel_subscriber_name` AS `tel_subscriber_name`
    ,`thp`.`tel_subscriber_has_port_startdate` AS `Reservation_Date`
    ,`p`.`port_serialnum` AS `port_number`
    ,`p`.`port_current_speed` AS `port_speed`
    ,`p`.`idport` AS `idport`
    ,`p`.`port_status` AS `port_status`
    ,`isp`.`isp_en_name` AS `isp_en_name`
    ,`c`.`contract_enname` AS `contract_enname`
    ,`mdf`.`mdf_room_arname` AS `mdf_room_arname`
    ,`mdf`.`idmdf_room` AS `idmdf_room`
    ,`c`.`idcontract` AS `contract_id`
    ,`isp`.`idisp` AS `isp_id`
FROM (
    (
        (
            (
                (
                    (
                        `tel_subscriber` `s` INNER JOIN `tel_subscriber_has_port` `thp` ON (
                                (
                                    (`s`.`idtel_subscriber` = `thp`.`tel_subscriber_idtel_subscriber`)
                                    AND (`thp`.`tel_subscriber_has_port_status` = 'active')
                                    )
                                )
                        ) INNER JOIN `port` `p` ON ((`p`.`idport` = `thp`.`port_idport`))
                    ) INNER JOIN `isp_has_port` `ihp` ON (
                        (
                            (`p`.`idport` = `ihp`.`port_idport`)
                            AND (`ihp`.`isp_has_port_status` = 'Active')
                            )
                        )
                ) INNER JOIN `isp` ON ((`ihp`.`isp_idisp` = `isp`.`idisp`))
            ) INNER JOIN `mdf_room` `mdf` ON ((`mdf`.`idmdf_room` = `p`.`mdf_room_idmdf_room`))
        ) INNER JOIN `contract` `c` ON ((`c`.`idcontract` = `p`.`contract_idcontract`))
    )
```

as you can see there is 7 joins between these tables. 
when I try to search in this view about any factor (1 or multiple criteria), it's too slow (more than 10 minutes with no result).
when I try to search in each table I get the result with maximum time of 5 seconds.
The count of records in each table are:

- mdf_room: 538
- tel_subscriber: 798019
- tel_subscriber_has_port: 790989
- port: 797174
- isp: 22
- isp_has_port: 810676
- contract: 25

I tried to explain the query in [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFpHn.png).

what can I do to search with a proper time about the information I want?

Comment: Ccan you tell in english what information your query shoud return?

Comment: @Meier this query is to build a view based on information from multiple tables. it contains the information I want to search about only. I have a search (filter) form including all of these columns. and the user can search on any criteria of them.

Comment: Do you have indices on the columns you're selecting on which the user can search?  Adding restrictions to the view based on non-indexed columns may be the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use [Join with Subquery First](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12309892/mysql-subquery-inside-a-left-join).

The problem is that you are joining 7 tables (4 of them have about one million records) which will get mysql server crazy.

To overcome this problem try to join with the interesting data you want, by joining with subquery including the condition inside of it.

**Example:**

First case:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.*
from table1 t1 join table2 t2 on (t1.id = t2.fkid)
where t2.attr1 = 'foo'
```

Second case:

```
select t1.*, t2_1.*
from table1 t1 join (select t2.* from table2 t2 where t2.attr1 = 'foo') t2_1
on t1.id = t2_1.fkid
```

when you have so many joins this would be useful. with no more than 2 or 3 joins the traditional `join then search` way would be useful too.

Answer (score 0):

Use `EXPLAIN` on your query to understand MySQL's query plan.  Create appropriate indices to prevent table scans.  Here are some links for your reference:

[Understanding the Query Execution Plan](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/execution-plan-information.html)

[MySQL Explain Explained](http://www.slideshare.net/phpcodemonkey/mysql-explain-explained)

If you post the results of the `EXPLAIN` query, you may get more specific suggestions.

Comment: I edited the question to show the results of EXPLAIN query.